# Is $y=|x^3|$ a smooth function?

Tags: functions, derivatives

Is this a smooth function? $y=|x^3|$

The graph of this function has no sharp cuts or corners, so I think it is a smooth function but someone told me that it's not.

Comment: *Smooth* means the function as derivatives of **all** orders, not that is has no "sharp cuts or corner". This last description is vague, and it cannot be taken as the definition of what *smooth* means.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can check that
$$
f'(x)=3x^2\operatorname{sign}(x)\\
f''(x)=6x\operatorname{sign}(x)\\
f'''(x)=6\operatorname{sign}(x)
$$
Since $f'''$ is discontinuous at zero then $f\notin C^2(\mathbb{R})$. Hence $f$ is not smooth.

Comment: Just to add to this nice answer, smooth (while meant to be a visually descriptive term) has a specific definition - it means that derivatives of all orders exist, so when you are asked if a function $f(x)$ is smooth, you should check if $f$ is infinitely differentiable.

Comment: You are right @AWertheim. I went on its deceptive graph, where it looks quite smooth. :) But by definition, when we see its behavior on a particular point (0) it's derivatives cease to be continuous.
It makes sense to me now :)
Thank you buddies Norbert and Clement C.

Comment: Typo: $f'''(x)=6\operatorname{sign}(x)$.

Answer (score 5):

Look at the origin: what is the behaviour at $0$? Is it differentiable? How many times? ($0$ is the only potentially "problematic" point).